# Access UTM parameters inside AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to access the addition parameter[utm_campaign] inside an email to supply it to a connected app using an HTML attribute. How can I fetch the attribute?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access it at send time inside the email, or that you want to grab it via API or something to fill into your app?

Comment: Access it at the send time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [personalization strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) below:

> **Analytics**
> The areas to enter these strings in the application are only available if you have web analytics functionality enabled in your account. To enable web analytics, contact your representative.
>
> `%%AdditionalInfo_%%` -    You can enter this string value in the Send Wizard as part of a Guided Send when the analytic connector is enabled.

and

```
%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%

%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%

%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%

%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%

%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%
```